# i can get correct result in sqlite3 but wrong in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

This is in sqlite3

[image]

This is in android studio
[image]

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: `sqlite3.exe` in the Windows console often does not handle UTF-8 correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you query should be

```
Select city1, city from city where city like "beijing";
```

You are trying to equate your table name instead of a column name

Comment: CREATE TABLE "city" (
"_id"  integer,
"cn"  text,
"city"  text,
"city1"  text,
"city2"  text,
"city3"  text
);

Comment: Ok, but look at your query, you are selecting only city1 from the city table and you want to use city you did not select as a condition in the query. May be you should write - Select city, city1 from city where city like "beijing";

Comment: Having a column that you filter on but don't select is perfectly fine. OP is using City1 in both of his example.